# How can I get a defi site source code?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tron

I'm trying to expose a defi scam website which copycats a famous platform on TRX blockchain. I have their transaction address, but no source code or website's contract address. I was wondering if there's any ways in solidity to extract that. getting their ABI also would be nice but I know that's just not gonna happen.

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible to view transactions and addresses on the Tron blockchain using a block explorer like Tronscan, obtaining the source code or the contract ABI from a transaction address alone is not feasible.

Solidity or the blockchain itself doesn't provide a feature to extract the code from a transaction address.

If the creators of the scam website haven't voluntarily verified their contract and uploaded the source code, it's extremely difficult to retrieve it.

Therefore, it's recommended to report the scam site to the appropriate authorities for further investigation.